# Android activity doesn't close completely

Tags: java, android, crosswalk-runtime

I have a javascript interface that I am using with crosswalk, and it has a `closeActivity` method. The interface looks like this:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

    private Activity activity;

    public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /**
     * Starts a new activity
     * @param page
     * @return
     */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public boolean openActivity(String page){
        if(isConnected()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, GenericActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("page", page);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the current activity
     */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void closeActivity(){
        activity.finish();
    }
}
```

Here is the activity that gets launched:

```
public class GenericActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_generic);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String page = intent.getStringExtra("page");

        XWalkView xWalkWebView = (XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebView);

        // Turn on debugging if we are in DEBUG mode
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);
            xWalkWebView.clearCache(true);
        }

        // Add the connector to talk to/from javascript
        JavaScriptInterface i = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
        xWalkWebView.addJavascriptInterface(i, "jsConnector");

        // Load the base file
        xWalkWebView.loadAppFromManifest("file:///android_asset/manifest.json", null);
        xWalkWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + page + ".html", null);
    }
}
```

When I call `closeActivity` the activity visually goes away, but in the chrome inspector ([chrome://inspect](http://chrome://inspect)), I can still see the crosswalk `webview`. Why is it still there and how can I close it?

Comment: Not too sure why that is happening. You could override onDestroy() inside GenericActivity, and remove/hide the webView yourself in that method.

Comment: doing that, it still is displayed in the inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! this was a super easy fix.

In the activity, all I needed was to add `view.onDestroy()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    XWalkView view = (XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebView);
    view.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
    finish();
}
```